# Sort by array gives empty array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 array when one of the array is empty and sortby  then it gives empty array

```
$first = [];
$second = ['created_at'=>2];
$third= [$first , $second];
$res = collect($third)->sortBy('created_at')->first();
dd($res);
```

if both array have value then it proper run. issue comes when one of array is empty. i need other array which is not empty. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace :

```
$res = collect($third)->sortBy('created_at')->first();
```

by:

```
$res = collect($third)->sortBy('created_at')->filter(function($value) {return !empty($value);})->first();
```

this will remove any empty array from the result of the sort

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$first = collect([]);
$second = collect(['created_at'=>2]);

$third = $first->push($second)->sortBy('created_at')->first();
```

Comment: i am facing one issue in stripe on live mode.. can you tell me the solution.. actually it works fine when on test mode but on live mode when on click button 3dsecure popup open after verification it close then it not further run .. even not go in method you can find this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71322782/stripe-on-test-mode-works-fine-but-on-live-mode-it-does-not-work-in-laravel